# Form field depending of another field value

Tags: django

```
# example objects:
# free
# paid
class ItemType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)


class Item(forms.ModelForm):
    title = models.CharField(...)
    item_type = models.ForeignKey(ItemType)
    destination_free = models.CharField(...)
    destination_paid = models.CharField(...)
```

How can I display `destination_free` and `destination_paid` field depending of `item_type` value? So if `item_type` is free my form should display `destination_free` but if `item_type` is paid my form should display `destination_paid` field.

Comment: you are using `models` field in you formset? What exactly you want to do?

Comment: @MHassan I want to display in my template `destination_free` field or `destination_paid` field depending of selected `item_type` field.

Comment: If you are OK with writing some `javascript`, you can hide both form fields and show one of them after user select `item_type` with some javascript code. If you are ok with this solution and need help, i can show you an example.

Comment: @alix I will be thankful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since i do not know your whole code, this is only base logic for client-side. You can change values if you need:

```
  $('#id_destination_free').hide(); // destination_free field
  $('#id_destination_paid').hide(); // destination_paid field

  $('#id_item_type').on('change', function(){
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    var valueSelected = this.value;
    if (valueSelected == 'something') {
      $('#id_destination_paid').hide();
      $('#id_destination_free').show();
    } else if (valueSelected == 'anotherthing') {
      $('#id_destination_free').hide();
      $('#id_destination_paid').show();
    }
    return false;
  });
```

Since you want `item_type` objects as select box in your form, this may be your `ModelForm`:

```
class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ItemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['item_type'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ItemType.objects.all())
```

And you can render this in html file like:

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```